# support issue with destructuring assignments in es5

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I had an issue with a part of code that uses destructuring assignments which is not supported in es5. (build problem with gulp).

I already removed all the es6 arrows and used functions instead but I don't know how to revert back the destructuring assignments to ES5:

```
var result2 = Object.values(
  zones.reduce(function (a, {id,name,card,request,res}) {
    a[id] || (a[id] = {id, card, name, unique_cards: new Set(), nb_carte: 0, request: {}, res: {} });
    a[id].unique_cards.add(card);
    a[id].nb_carte = a[id].unique_cards.size;
    Object.keys(request).forEach(function (k) {
      (a[id].request[k] = (a[id].request[k] || 0) + request[k])
    });
    Object.keys(res).forEach(function (k) {
      (a[id].res[k] = (a[id].res[k] || 0) + res[k])
    });
    return a;
  }, Object.create(null))
);
```

The actual error is:

> Destructuring assignments are not supported by current JavaScript version

Comment: how i would do it is use an object as param like `function (a, obj) {...}` then inside your function `var id = obj.id, card = obj.card, ...`

Comment: If you have a lot of ES6 code or want to write ES6 (which is a good idea), then you're better off transpiling your source code using Babel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the destrucutring, and assign the original object to a variable (`o` in the example). Then manually assign the needed properties to variables.

As [@Dehli noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55419900/support-issue-with-destructuring-assignments-in-es5/55419951?noredirect=1#comment97559068_55419951), you should also change the [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) to manual assignment as well.

```
var result2 = Object.values(
  zones.reduce(function(a, o) {
    var id = o.id, name = o.name, card = o.card, request = o.request, res = o.res;
    a[id] || (a[id] = {
      id: id, // change from shorthand property name
      card: card, // change from shorthand property name
      name: name, // change from shorthand property name
      unique_cards: new Set(),
      nb_carte: 0,
      request: {},
      res: {}
    });
    a[id].unique_cards.add(card);
    a[id].nb_carte = a[id].unique_cards.size;
    Object.keys(request).forEach(function(k) {
      (a[id].request[k] = (a[id].request[k] || 0) + request[k])
    });
    Object.keys(res).forEach(function(k) {
      (a[id].res[k] = (a[id].res[k] || 0) + res[k])
    });
    return a;
  }, Object.create(null))
);
```

Comment: Don't forget about `{ id: id, card: card ... }`on line 5